# Generating and displaying random platforms in pygame

Tags: random, pygame, generator, platform

So this is part of the code for my game, using pygame. I'm trying to generate random platforms (from 3 different options), store them in a list and then blit all platforms in the list to the screen. I am able to generate the platform shapes correctly but other than the first platform i'm unable to position them where i want them.

```
blue = (0, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

i = 0
c = 0


Done = True
globalplatpos = pygame.Surface([395, 30])
globalplat = globalplatpos.get_rect()

platform_dimensions = plattop, platleft, platw, plath = 0,0,0,0


def play():

#============GAME SETUP============
    SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
    TITLE = "Duality"
    SPEED = 10
    JUMPHEIGHT = 300
    JUMPCOUNT = 0
    JUMPSPEED = 15
    GRAVITY = 10
    STANDING = 1
    JUMPING = 0

    globalplatpos.fill(red)
    platform = globalplat
    platform.bottom = HEIGHT

    PLATFORM = []
    PLATPOS = []

    platstand = True

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    caption = pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    mainsprite = pygame.image.load("images\mainsprite.png")
    mainchar = mainsprite.get_rect()
    mainchar.left = 177.5
    mainchar.bottom = 570

    mirrsprite = pygame.image.load("images\mirrsprite.png")
    mirrchar = mirrsprite.get_rect()
    mirrchar.left = mainchar.left + 400
    mirrchar.bottom = mainchar.bottom
#============GAME SETUP============







#============PLATFORM GENERATOR============
    def platform_generator(platform):
        global globalplat
        global globalplatpos
        global platform_dimensions

        globalplat = platform.move(0,-60)
        globalplatpos.fill(red)

        lastplat = PLATFORM[len(PLATFORM) - 1]
        platheight = lastplat.top

        leftpos = pygame.Surface([131, 30])
        leftplat = leftpos.get_rect()

        centrepos = pygame.Surface([100, 30])
        centreplat = centrepos.get_rect() 

        rightpos = pygame.Surface([131, 30]) 
        rightplat = rightpos.get_rect()

        plat_type = random.randrange(0,3)

        if plat_type == 0:
            globalplat = leftplat
            globalplatpos = leftpos
            platform_dimensions = int(globalplat.top + 290), 0, 131, 30

        elif plat_type == 1:
            globalplat = centreplat
            globalplatpos = centrepos
            platform_dimensions = int(globalplat.top + 290), 132, 100, 30

        elif plat_type == 2:
            globalplat = rightplat
            globalplatpos = rightpos
            platform_dimensions = int(globalplat.top + 290), 233, 131, 30

        else:
            pass

        PLATFORM.append(globalplat)
        PLATPOS.append(globalplatpos)       

#============PLATFORM GENERATOR============







#============GAME LOOP============    
    Done = False
    while not Done:
        clock.tick(60)
        fps = clock.get_fps()
        print(fps)
        platform = globalplat
        platpos = globalplatpos



        mirrchar.left = mainchar.left + 406
        mirrchar.bottom = mainchar.bottom

        def update():
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
            screen.fill(blue)
            screen.blit(mainsprite, mainchar)
            screen.blit(mirrsprite, mirrchar)
            listpos = 0
            pos = PLATPOS[listpos]
            platshape = pygame.Rect(platform_dimensions)
            platform = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, platshape, 0)
            platpos = globalplatpos
            PLATFORM.append(platform)
            PLATPOS.append(platpos)
            for form in PLATFORM:
                pos = PLATPOS[listpos]
                listpos += 1
                screen.blit(pos, form)

            divpos = pygame.Rect(395, 0, 10, HEIGHT)
            divrect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, divpos, 0)
            pygame.display.update()




        global i
        if i == 0:
            globalplat.bottom = HEIGHT
            i = 1
            PLATFORM.append(globalplat)
            PLATPOS.append(globalplatpos)
            screen.blit(globalplatpos, globalplat)

        elif i == 1 and len(PLATFORM) < 10:
            platform_generator(platform)
            plat1 = PLATFORM[0]
            update()

        elif plat1.top > HEIGHT:
            plat1 = PLATFORM[0]
            pos1 = PLATPOS[0]
            del plat1
            del pos1

        else:
            update()





        if mainchar.left > 0: #MOVE LEFT
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a]:
                mainchar.left -= SPEED
        else:
            mainchar.left = 0

        if mainchar.right < 395: # MOVE RIGHT
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_d]:
                mainchar.right += SPEED
        else:
            mainchar.right = 395


        jump = pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_SPACE] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]


        platstand = mainchar.collidelist(PLATFORM)
        for form in PLATFORM:
            if mainchar.colliderect(form):
                STANDING = 1
                mainchar.bottom = form.top


        if JUMPING == 0:
            if mainchar.collidelist(PLATFORM) > -1:
                STANDING = 1


        if STANDING == 1:
            if jump:
                JUMPING = 1

        if JUMPING == 1:
            if JUMPCOUNT < JUMPHEIGHT/2:
                mainchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED
                mirrchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED
                JUMPCOUNT += JUMPSPEED
            elif JUMPCOUNT > JUMPHEIGHT/2 and JUMPCOUNT < JUMPHEIGHT * 0.75:
                mainchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED/2
                mirrchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED/2
                JUMPCOUNT += JUMPSPEED
            elif JUMPCOUNT > JUMPHEIGHT * 0.75 and JUMPCOUNT < JUMPHEIGHT:
                mainchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED/4
                mirrchar.bottom -= JUMPSPEED/4
                JUMPCOUNT += JUMPSPEED
            else:
                JUMPCOUNT = 0
                JUMPING = 0
                STANDING = 0
                jump = False

        if STANDING == 0:
            mainchar.bottom += GRAVITY
            mirrchar.bottom += GRAVITY


        def gameover():
            Done = True

        if mainchar.top > HEIGHT:
            gameover()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
            escape()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: Done = True

        update()
#============GAME LOOP============
```

Comment: Why you create `update()` in mainloop - create it once (before `while not Done`). Why do you create `screen` in `update()` - create it only once (before `while not Done`).

Comment: Why do you create `platform_generator()` inside `play()` ?

Comment: You could keep platforms and their positions as tuples `(platform, position)` or lists `[platform, position]` on one list `PLATFORM`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't run this example but I see one mistake in `blit()`

You use

```
screen.blit( position, surface )
```

but `blit()` expects

```
screen.blit( surface, position )
```

Read PyGame Documentation: [pygame.Surface.blit()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)